# func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL... not called in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` with a delegate.

The delegate reacts to clicks on an URL with:
`textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction)`

This works already with iOS 11,12 and 13
But it's not working on iOS 14. Someone an idea what might have changed?

Comment: It works fine for everyone else, so your job in asking your question is to give enough information to show how to make it _not_ work. Provide us with a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce what you are seeing. Thanks!

Comment: `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:)` (which is deprecated) or `extView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)`? Can you reproduce your example?

Comment: @Larme I am using the one with interaction

Comment: See, I can show you [an example that does work](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/ddd2b9f22660b61a2878cf60812a814ecc8b85b1/bk2ch10p507tabStops/TextTabTest/ViewController.swift). But you, the questioner, persist in not showing an example that _doesn't_ work. That is not a good way to ask the question.

Comment: @matt You are right, I provided not so much information so far. But as I said everything is running fine up to iOS 13, but not with iOS 14. So it's not some of the typical set up problems for textView delegates. I first wanted to know if someone had a similar problem.

Comment: @Patrick_K We are asking if that if you tried creating a new project with only a textView, a link and the delegate. Can you reproduce it then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found the solution for this problem. But first thanks for all your responses. Specially from @matt and @Larme.
I created an example for this problem, but it worked. So I compared with my real project and found the difference.
The textView is inside a table view cell. In my real project it was added directly to the cell and not to the content view.

Old: `cell.addSubview(textView)`

New: `cell.contentView.addSubview(textView)`

Everything worked fine with the old approach, besides my problem with not opening links in iOS14.
Maybe this might help someone in future.

Answer (score 4):

Things to keep in mind:

- The text view needs to be selectable and not editable.
- The text view's `dataDetectorTypes` needs to include `.link`.
- The view controller (or whoever you are) needs to adopt UITextViewDelegate, and the delegate method needs to a top level method of that view controller (not inside some other method).
- The interaction will never be `.preview` (it is a dead letter).

Answer (score 1):

put these two lines in viewDidload function

```
textView.delegate = self
textView.isSelectable = true
```

Comment: and the above function works for me in ios 14.2